# Can I disable copy/clone of work item?

Tags: tfs

We have customized out workitems to a far extent. Now the copy/clone are throwing exceptions. Can I disable copy/clone work item in TFS? Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to solve the problem that prevents you from copying in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you are meaning the feature as below screenshot:

[image]

There is no way to disable the feature directly in TFS, unless you restrict the user's related permission.

The user which want to copy/clone work item must have your **View work items in this node**, and your **Edit work items in this node** permissions set to **Allow**.

More details please refer this tutorial: **[Copy or clone work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=browser)**